# What are the possible issues with having a small timeout time in Python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

Basically, I want to send a post request to my server from a function. However, I don't want anything back, so I just want to send the request and forget about it, and close my function. This is because the function I'm running needs to complete running within a small time-frame. My code looks like this:

```
def my_function(url, payload):
    try:
        requests.post(url, data=payload, timeout=1)
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: 
        return 'Done'
```

As you can see, the timeout is set to 1 second, which means many times the function will simply return 'Done', which is completely fine. What are the possible issues I might facing using this system?

Can I be reasonably sure that the request will **always** be sent to the other server? I don't care about failures in the other server, I just want the request to hit it.

Note: Please no answers about threads or parallel processing. Obviously, I am aware of these things, however, I simply cannot use these things in my context.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You will have elaborate more about what is the expectation when the request fails for some reason e.g.  you would retry or just fatal failure.

Comment: @vk-code I updated it. I don't care about failures or retrying. I just want the request to hit the server and timing out.